# What do I use instead of select_tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use tags in order to reference a field in my controller BUT I have learned that you cannot use select_tag in rails :(.

My goal is to only allow the user to use either the select field or the text_field but not both. What is a solution that I can look into? I would prefer not to use a gem. I tried Select 2 to allow the user to enter whatever they want but I just don't like the functionality of it. This is what I would like to use alternatively.

```
example.html

<div class="form-group row">
      <%= f.label 'Type', class: 'col-2 col-form-label' %>
      <div class="col-10">
         <%= f.select_tag(:example_type,"example_type_1", @example_types, {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control selectpicker', data: {'live-search' => 'true'}) %>
         <%= f.text_field_tag :example_type,"example_type_2", class: 'form-control', placeholder: "If your example type is not listed, add it here. " %>
      </div>
    </div>

example_controller.rb
def create
 .......

    if params[:example_type_1] != nil && params[:example_type_2] != nil 
      redirect_to '', notice: 'Must enter a type'
    elsif params[:example_type_1] == nil && params[:example_type_2] == nil 
      redirect_to '', notice: 'Please only use one field for type' 
    elsif params[:example_type_1] == nil 
      @example.example_types == params[:example_type_2]
    else
      @example.example_types == params[:example_type_1]
    end
end
```

Comment: "BUT I have learned that you cannot use select_tag in rails" - where on earth are you getting this nonsense from?

Comment: I'm getting this error
undefined method `select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00007ff01bc58f88>
Did you mean?  select

Comment: Yes. Thats because you're calling it on a FormBuilder instance. Any of the helper methods that end with `_tag` are low level [tag helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag). If you just call it on the view context `<%= select_tag ... %>`  it works just fine. `FormBuilder` has a differnent set of methods that are built on top of the low level helpers.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease